# Change in what from addresses can be used in GmailApp Sendemail: must be "treat as alias" now?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have scripts I've authorized that send email from one of my send-as email addresses; however, that particular address was not checked as "treat as alias" in the past (Settings > Accounts > Send Mail as > edit info > uncheck "treat as alias"). In the past weeks, scripts that used this method have failed with the error "Execution failed: Invalid argument: nontreatasaliassendasaccount@____.edu.

I can't find documentation of this change. Is this how the from parameter will work going forward?

```
//---abbreviated script (last line throws error)---
function sendFormByEmail(e) {  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var message =""; 
var columns = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastColumn).getValues()[0];

//collate form questions/answers to send in email  
for (var keys in columns) 
var questionName = columns[keys];
//creates list of all questions and answers 
if (e.namedValues[questionName] && (e.namedValues[questionName] != "") ){
message += "<b>" + questionName + "<\/b>" + ": "+
e.namedValues[questionName] + "<br>"; 
}
}

//send mail to requestor with form questions/emails
//(sent from a non-primary send-as email address 
//that is NOT marked as an alias in Settings > Accounts > Send Mail As)
GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient@___.edu", "Thanks for your request", "",
{htmlBody: message, from:"nontreatasaliassendasaccount@_____.edu"});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, also can you post the code you are using?

Comment: I added abbreviated script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing anything on my side, I am once again able to send email using `GmailApp.sendEmail` and specifying the *from email address* as a secondary send-as account that is not an alias:

#### All of a Sudden Works Again

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient@___.edu", "Thanks for your request", "",
{htmlBody: message, from:"not_treat_as_alias_send_as_account@_____.edu"});
```

#### Also Works

(and did during the period when the above did not)

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient@___.edu", "Thanks for your request", "",
{htmlBody: message, from:"alias_send_as_account@_____.edu"});
```

I never found documentation as to the change in functionality.